# What separates a cyclic polytope from a projective polytope?

Tags: complex-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes

I am having trouble understanding the difference between a cyclic polytope and a convex projective polytope as positive geometries.

The link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04541.pdf is the source of where I am getting the notions of the cyclic polytope, the convex projective polytope, and positive geometries.

It mentions cyclic polytopes and convex projective polytopes as subtypes of projective polytopes but their definitions is where I am getting confused. It seems to me that cyclic polytopes are convex projective polytopes with positive ordered minors of a matrix Z.

Is my understanding correct? Are cyclic polytopes special convex projective polytopes, or are they separate notions of special projective polytopes.